# Issue with OSX 10.9 multiple desktops

Tags: java, macos, osx-mavericks

I run about multiple desktops at all times and if I stay on the desktop that My App is running on everything seems fine. If I move away from the desktop with my app on and work on a different desktop this is where my app will stop downloading once it has finished its current process, it will switch to the next process but will not start next downloading.

I identified that that it might be virtual desktop related. If I switch all desktops for a second then operation works fine.

I was working on 10.8 OS X where my app (built in java) was working absolutely fine.
but as I upgraded it to 10.9, I am facing problem like above.

Is that have any solution or It is a bug of 10.9 OS X.

Comment: More likely a bug in Java...

Comment: well, you've identified how to reproduce the problem, what debugging steps have you performed?

Comment: sounds like app nap. Once the application is out of view of the user it gets suspended.

Comment: You can easily test if it is app nap causing the problem. Right click on the application and select 'Get Info'. There's a check box to 'Prevent App Nap'